# if non-transnational method calling a transnational method in same class In Spring declarative transaction management

Tags: spring-transactions

I have a scenario where I need to call transactional method in loop to persist single record from non-transactional method in same class..

Is this possible to implement using Spring declarative transaction management?

I configured txManager in xml file as below:

```
<bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

and made advice to cover all service methods.
But in one service I need to call a method from other method.

My class looks like this.

```
public class Test{
        saveAllRecords(){
           // some required processing
           for(i=0;i<10;i++)
             {
        // some required processing before calling save one record
                    saveOneRecord();}
              }

             @Transactional
             saveOneRecord()
              {
              }
            }

My Questions are 
1)how to make only method transnational..?
2) How do i make both different transaction..? like as soon as method2() execution finished i should see one record in database..
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define an advice to make all your methods respect transactional annotation. You would need to specify just this in your context configuration and any method annotated with `@Transactional` will be transactional.

`<tx:annotation-driven/>`

You can add the propagation for the transaction as [REQUIRES_NEW](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW). It will cause a new transaction to open every time this method is executed.

`@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

However, be aware that having multiple transactions in a for loop is a highly discouraged as it can hammer database and degrade performance in case of high data transactions.